# Setting focus to a control inside a usercontrol in WPF occured not displaying the view in the IDE

Tags: wpf, mvvm, setfocus

When i add this.IsVisibleChanged in the constructor it not showing the view .So basically i tried with focus method in the xaml view but it doesn't work well.So i add this and working well.Only issue is the design view is not displaying.It through an exception.

```html
//Constructor
public LoginControl()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 this.IsVisibleChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(LoginControl_IsVisibleChanged); 
}

void LoginControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
 if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
 {
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
  new Action(delegate()
  {
   txtPassword.Focus();
  }));
 } 
}
```

Comment: please don't use code snippet if the shown code is not runnable. To achieve the formatting as code simply use 4 spaces at the beginning of a line. For code-highlighting, the language tag is needed. See this help page on how to format posts: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer

Remove the line

```html
this.IsVisibleChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler
          (LoginControl_IsVisibleChanged);
```

Enable IsVisibleChanged property in the LoginControl's opening tag and bind the LoginControl_IsVisibleChanged method.

Paste the content of the method LoginControl_IsVisibleChanged inside

```html
void LoginControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) 
  {
   if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
   {
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
  new Action(delegate()
  {
   txtPassword.Focus();
  }));
   } 
    }
}
```